# vim substitute within block selection on one line

Tags: vim, substitution

I have the following expression in a latex file

```
\begin{dfn} \tag{Diagram $$ over a trisp $\Delta$}
          \label{dfn:Diagram D over a trisp Delta}
```

now i want to substitute all the spaces in the brackets on the second line with `:`.
my idea was to visual select the expression by `v%` while being on one of the brackets and then `:s/\ /:/g` but this replaces all whitespaces and results in

```
::::::::::::::\label{dfn:Diagram::over:a:trisp:Delta}
```

which results in the task of removing the `:` before the `\label{…}`
as vim is a very powerful editor - there should be an easier way, that I don't know yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the first `{`, press `v`, press `%`. This will visually select the text between `{` and `}`. Then press `:` and enter `s/\%V\ /:/g` in your minibar. See this for explanation:

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection

Note that otherwise `g` will replace all on the current line.

Comment: i knew about the `g` replacing all on the line - but the `\%V` is new to me